# Why doesn't css styles apply to html correctly in django?

Tags: html, css, django

Only body styling work in django, I use static files to get css. I tried even commenting out body part css, but it still works, I don't know how, I don't know why, please help! (I've used  collectstatic, so it's not because of that). I've inserted static_root and url and other things in setting to, but it didn't help either.

```css
body{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #8D7D77;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------NAV-BAR-UPPER------------------------------------------ */

.nav-bar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.nav-bar img{
    max-width: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.nav-bar ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
}

.nav-bar ul li{
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.nav-bar ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.nav-bar ul a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8D7D77;
    background-color: white;
}

.search-bar{
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color:  #C2B280;
    font-size: 110%;
}

.search-bar:focus{
    border-style:none;
}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/main.css' %}" />
  <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/logomogo.png' %}" />
  <title>BookShelf</title>

</head>
<body>
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>

And here's navbar

{% load static%}
<header>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <a href="">
      <img src="{% static 'images/logo-white.png' %}" alt="BookShelf Logo" />
    </a>
    <input type="search" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

  <div class="lower-nav-bar">
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="main.html">Books</a></li>
              <li><a href="reviews-page.html">Reviews</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Users</a></li>
              <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried hard-reloading your page or clearing the cache? Often CSS files will not be renewed every time the page is refreshed

Comment: Can you use .js static files? Or any static files at all?

Comment: Clearing cache helped, thank you!